# wildcard SSL/TLS certificate for second-level domain rejected by browsers

Tags: security, dns, ssl-certificate, wildcard-subdomain

I'm trying to create certificate for both `test` and `*.test`. I'm using `minica` to generate it and everything goes well (alt names are added):

```
X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:*.test, DNS:test
```

(and CA certificate is added to browsers' trusted root certification authorities store)
 but the certificate is rejected by both chrome and firefox.

Comment: .test is not a valid dns name. Remove the period at the front of `.test`

Comment: Assuming you did not use weak certificate with Sha1 or 1024 length modulus, I think the latest versions of browsers also expect IPs in subject alternative name, so you can try adding them in your certificate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can create a valid certificate for second-level domain or even top level domain those certificates won't be respected by the browsers for security reasons (i.e. certificate for *.com would be very dangerous). So even though `test` is a reserved domain name that can't be registered by any registrar, the certificate will be rejected.

When you try to do this with `mkcert` you'll get pretty nice warning:

`Warning: many browsers don't support second-level wildcards like *.test ⚠️`

Use i.e. `app.test` + `*.app.test` instead.

Comment: Browsers typically use the Public Suffix List, and also for cookies management, to see where boundaries exist and hence where wildcarding should not be allowed.